# How can I create a menu animated with two arrows?

Tags: xcode, button, menu, animated

I have a menu animated with two arrows
one in the left of the button and one in the right of the button
the direction of the arrow is right for the right arrow and left for the left arrow

I want when I click in the arrow in the right show me another one without exit the corrent view ,the same for the left arrow but he show me another button(option) to choose

and when I click on the right or the left button I want that he show me the new button with an animation it appears like a train animation when he change the button

can you give me an idea how can I do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `UIScrollView` with `UIButtons` and put two `UIButtons` to left and right scroll.
You can follow this tutorial for it -

http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/

Comment: thinks saadnib but this is  not what I a want to do I want a scroll view horizantal(from right to left) not vertical

Comment: in my interface there is a button named Forme1 and two arrows one on the left and on the right of the button I want when I click on the arrow on the right/left show me another button : button 2(Forme2) with an animation